# Synchronising SQL Server Compact database to work with an online database in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web-services, sql-server-ce

I am creating a desktop application and the users would like to view information from the application online, on a website that I would create.

The problem is my application is using SQL Server Compact as the database. I really need help on how to create a web service that can get data from the local desktop application. The users (aka admin of the app) should also be able to make changes from the website that would affect the app. They also want to see information such as inventory, contact, etc from the app on the website.

I have created the desktop app but have no clue on creating the web app / service or synchronizing the local database to the online one.

Comment: There are different ways that leads to rome, you'll have to figure it out on your own. We can help you solve code issues

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you **really** need to have a local database and to keep it in sync with the online one? As far as I understood, you'll develop both of them so you'll have the control. Therefore the first logical step I see here is to create a REST API [1,2,3] and provide *end-points* both to read and write from your online database. For instance, if you want to build a simple API to register and login users, it should have at these *end-points* (operations):

- POST /users/register
- GET /users/:id
- PUT /users/:id
- POST /users/login
- DELETE /users/logout

So you can register a new user, see the data in his profile and be able to update it and, of course, *log-in* and *log-out*.

Now both your *online* and *desktop* applications can be clients of the API. You can add, edit and remove products in one of them and the changes will appear in the other one as well. Of course I am making some assumptions here (no need to have real-time updates, desktop client can have a *always on* connection, the size of the response *payloads* are not huge, etc).

If you need to have a local database anyway, you can have a field *updatedAt* in the tables you want to be in sync so the *desktop* application can query the API only to get the changes produced after a given date, decreasing the *payload* of the API response (and the bandwidth used, if that matters). Anyway, I think this step is an optimization to the real problem, so you might only think in all of this (having a local DB, keeping track of the changes and syncing...) after you thought carefully about the API and the clients first. Answering the following questions probably can help you to take a conscious decision:

- How many users will you have concurrently?
- How many items (DB records) will you have in the system?

If the answer is less than 100 users and a thousand of records, you probably should not worry about synchronization. However we can only help you with more information about the requirements of the system.

References:

1. http://www.restapitutorial.com/
2. https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design
3. http://mattgemmell.com/api-design/

Best regards and a happy new year,
João

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Users are less than 100 and db records may run into thousands in time